# What is a notation for the minimal ordinal of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: notation, set-theory, ordinals

What is a notation for the minimal ordinal of $\mathbb{R}$?

I know that $\beth_1$ and $\mathfrak{c}$ designate the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$, and that $\Omega$ denotes the smallest uncountable ordinal, and that $\aleph_1$ denotes the first uncountable cardinal, and that $\Omega$ and $\beth_1$ and $\aleph_1$ are all equipollent if CH is true, but what is a notation for the smallest ordinal equipollent to $\mathbb{R}$ which doesn't implicitly assume any position on CH?

Comment: If cardinals are defined [as initial ordinals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_cardinal_assignment), then $\mathfrak c$ is what you want.

Comment: The first uncountable ordinal is $\omega_1$; I’ve seen $\Omega$ used only in contexts in which most readers would have minimal familiarity with infinite ordinals at all.

Comment: I think I learned $\Omega$ from Patrick Suppes' Axiomatic Set Theory?  I understood it to denote the first uncountable ordinal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the axiom of choice and $\frak c$ is a well-ordered cardinal, it means that $\frak c$ is an initial ordinal, namely it is the least ordinal which can be put in bijection with the real numbers.

It is not uncommon to see $\alpha<\frak c$.

If one wishes to be completely formal and separate the cardinal and ordinal form, one can write:

> Let $\aleph_\alpha$ be the cardinality of the continuum. We enumerate $\mathbb R$ as $\{x_\beta\mid \beta<\omega_\alpha\}$ ...

Comment: That is how I consider it privately.  Is it unambiguous to refer to $\frak c$ as an ordinal?

Comment: Well-ordered cardinals **are** ordinals.

Comment: Is $\frak c$ assumed to denote a well-ordered cardinal?

Comment: @Dan: When assuming the continuum can be well-ordered. If it cannot be well-ordered then there is no ordinal that $\mathbb R$ can be put in bijection with anyway.

Comment: I see, given AC, $\frak{c}$ unambiguously denotes a specific ordinal.  But otherwise maybe there is no ordinal at all it is equipollent to.

Comment: @Dan: To be more accurate, $\frak c$ denotes an ordinal when the real numbers are assumed (or can be proved) to be well-orderable. Even if choice fails as a whole.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There need not be *any* ordinal equipollent to $\Bbb R$, so there isn't really a standard notation for the least such (at least, none that I'm aware of). Note also that $\omega_1$ is typically used to denote the least uncountable ordinal, except when the reader is expected to have little to no familiarity with ordinals, in which case $\Omega$ is used instead. (Thanks, Brian, for prompting the clarification.)

More generally, we'll typically take $\omega_\alpha$ to be the least ordinal having the cardinal $\aleph_\alpha$. In fact, we'll take $\omega_\alpha$ and $\aleph_\alpha$ to be the *same thing*. We'll choose one notation over the other depending on whether we're talking about cardinalities or order types, or whether we're using cardinal arithmetic or ordinal arithmetic.

If we assume AC (or at least enough choice so that $\Bbb R$ is well-ordered), then the cardinal of $\Bbb R$--that is $\mathfrak{c}$--can be taken to be an ordinal, in particular the least ordinal equipollent to $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Even if AC is assumed?

Comment: I would go further: use of $\Omega$ is almost entirely limited to contexts in which readers are expected to have little familiarity with infinite ordinals.

Comment: Fair point, Brian. Thanks.